# Sequelize where condition used for included model

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models associated -> Order belongs to Phase and I want to use where clause when selecting the orders which have the chosen phase.projectId.

```
models.Order.findAll( {
        attributes:[
            'id',
            'product_id',
            'phase_id',
            [models.Order.sequelize.fn('sum', models.Order.sequelize.col('invoiced')), 'invoiced_quantity'],
        ],
        include: [{model:models.Phase, as:'phase', required: true}],
        where:{'$phase.projectId$': chosenProject.id},
        group:[
            'product_id'
        ],
        raw: true
    })
```

but it creates an error Unknown column 'phase.projectId' in 'where clause'

Is it possible to use where clause for included models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use where clause in include.

```
models.Order.findAll( {
        attributes:[
            'id',
            'product_id',
            'phase_id',
            [models.Order.sequelize.fn('sum', models.Order.sequelize.col('invoiced')), 'invoiced_quantity'],
        ],
        include: [{model:models.Phase, as:'phase', where: {id: chosenProject.id}],
        group:[
            'product_id'
        ],
        raw: true
    })
```

And the where clause in include make inner join (w/o `required: true` option).

Comment: include: [{model:models.Phase, as:'phase', where: {id: chosenProject.id}]is worked another option which I found while trying is outside the include "where:{'$phase.project_id$': chosenProject.id}". The "project_id" is phase tables field name